# Compare two Datetimes one from Datetimepicker and one from MySql Database

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have a strange problem...I have a MySql db with some columns and one of the column is date_purchased which is of type date_time.

I am using C# and made a DatetimePicker and user selects a date.

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        varDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;

    }
```

Now the problem is I have to compare the two datetimes (one from the database and one from the User) and I should display the records that are less than the date selected by the user(varDate).

```
select * from orders where date_purchased < = '" + varDate + "'";
```

I am executing this query but i am getting an exception

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '12/25/2011 8:01:31 PM'' at line 1
```

I wrote the connection string and all and I am struck at the query.
Any Help will be much appreciated...
Thanks,
Subash

Comment: Can you please provide more information? Eg: table structure, what you need to select, etc. By the way "Date_time" is not a valid mySQL datatype, you mean "datetime" right?

Comment: Have you tried converting to the same type and then comparing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given any details on what you are using to run the select query; however, if you are using the connector provided by Mysql (Connector/Net) then you should be using parameters. Which would look something like this:

```
String sql = "select * from orders where date_purchased < @DatePurchased";

MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("DatePurchased", MySqlType.DateTime).Value = varDate; 
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

Using parameters will ensure the values are converted and will also prevent [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like where DBdatetime < "'" + vardate + "'"

One word of caution, check the formats of the two dates.  I had a problem in a previous app where the DB had seconds and milliseconds, whereas the app provided just a data and set the time to 00:00.  This resulted in records for the current date not showing in the result set.  Thus, I had to add 23:59 to the date to get all the records for the current day.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the values between the two data using the following **MySQL Query**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE dbvalue < varData
```